# how do query all the information in an nested array to the dom if all the arrays are different lengths?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

how do i output the features category even though the lengths of the arrays are different? i have been able to output the code using projects.features[1] but im not sure what to do as the nested array length are different sizes.

```
const peet = document.querySelector('.projectInserts');

const projects = [
  {"Title":"InstaJam",
   "image":"img/ig.jpg",
   "Gif":"gif-title",
   "Github":"github",
   "description":["first","second", "third"],
   "features":["PHP / Laravel", "Html and CSS", "Blade", "Composer", 
    "User authentication", "MySQL" 
    ],
   "Link":"link",
   "class": "app"
 },
  {"Title":"Kayak HTML Email",
   "image":"img/kayak.png",
   "Gif":"gif-title",
   "Github":"github",
   "description":["first","second", "third"],
   "features":[ 
    "User authentication", "MySQL" 
    ],
   "Link":"link"
 },
```

Comment: What do you mean by output? Output to the page in nice HTML? or just to the console?

Comment: @QurakNerd i want to output it to an html page

Comment: @hev1 that is very close! im just not sure how to use that so that i can output it in HTML instead of the console.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are wanting but this will get all your features in one array.

```
let getIndividualFeatures = []

for(let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++){
    getIndividualFeatures.push(projects[i].features)
}

let allFeatures = [].concat.apply([], getIndividualFeatures);

console.log(allFeatures)
```

EDIT: If you are wanting to keep them separated, then check the `console.log(getIndividualFeatures)` before `allFeatures` is initiated.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array of objects using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and loop over the features property of each object.

```js
const projects = [
  {"Title":"InstaJam",
   "image":"img/ig.jpg",
   "Gif":"gif-title",
   "Github":"github",
   "description":["first","second", "third"],
   "features":["PHP / Laravel", "Html and CSS", "Blade", "Composer", 
    "User authentication", "MySQL" 
    ],
   "Link":"link",
   "class": "app"
 },
  {"Title":"Kayak HTML Email",
   "image":"img/kayak.png",
   "Gif":"gif-title",
   "Github":"github",
   "description":["first","second", "third"],
   "features":[ 
    "User authentication", "MySQL" 
    ],
   "Link":"link"
 },
 ];
 const peet = document.querySelectorAll('.projectInserts');
 projects.forEach((project,i)=>{
    peet[i].textContent += "Title: " + project.Title + "\n";
    peet[i].textContent += "Features:\n";
    project.features.forEach(feature=>peet[i].textContent+=feature+"\n");
});
```

```css
.projectInserts {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<pre class="projectInserts"></pre>
<pre class="projectInserts"></pre>
```

Comment: the code works but im having trouble displaying it how i want it. i posted the whole code under your code. i want display each project in a modal and list all the features. when i used your code everything displayed in only 1 modal. how can i fix this problem?

Comment: the code isnt working. i keep getting this error " Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined".

Comment: @Msingh17 What error does the snippet give you? It is working for me.

Comment: i get an " Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined" error

Comment: @Msingh17 What browser and version of it are you using?